# Native C#: Reconstructing a Decimal number from its bit representation

Tags: c#

```
typedef struct
{
    union {
        uint32_t ss32;    
        struct {
            unsigned int reserved1 : 16;
            unsigned int scale : 8;
            unsigned int reserved2 : 7;
            unsigned int sign : 1;
        } signscale;
    } u;
    uint32_t hi32;
    uint32_t lo32;
    uint32_t mid32;
} decimal_repr;
```

Given that Decimal structure, how can I reconstruct its internal data into a human readable number e.g 123456.987654000123456 ? I couldn't find any document that explains the Decimal structure (how many bits to left or right shift, it's fraction, mantissa etc).

I also find the Decimal class makes a link to `libdec` but I couldn't find the lib anywhere in the project source code. If any, I sure would like to only reuse it.

**Edit**

I'm still stuck at 2 issues:

1. If I use the above formula to calculate the final output result, it will then look like I fall back into normal computations (mult,div,pow) with ordinary built-in types (e.g 10000/3.0 = 333.3333) in which the number of digits is then limited by the compiler by default.
2. In a decimal class, I only have 4 private members (lo,hi,mid,flags) in which `flags` is a 16 bit left-shifted value of `scale` defined in the above struct; AND in case the input value is negative, flags must be masked or set its lowest significant bit values with 0x8000000. Now that given the above struct data, I would like to initialize the Decimal class member especially the `flags`. 
   Sure I can right-shift 16 bits the `scale` value to get `flags` but then in case the `sign` is 1 which is negative input value, I am dumb about the inverse operation of 
   `flags|=0x8000000`. That is, to eliminate the least significant bit values out of the previously shifted scale to get the original `flags`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(-1)^sign*(hi32*2^64+mid32*2^32+lo32)/10^scale

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10 raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Edit:

1. You have to deal with long arithmetic somehow. Decimal is largest build-in numeric type, so you can not represent all possible decimal values in single variable of other build-in type.
2. Not completely understand your question. `decimal_repr` directly corresponds to `Decimal` struct, it have same fields in same order. `flags` corresponds to `ss32`, `hi` to `hi32`, `lo` to `lo32` and `mid` to `mid32`. So if you have your data struct, then you already have Decimal struct, no conversion is needed. And if you want to clear `sing` flag from `flags`, then you can do that: `flags&=0x7fffffff`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you PetSerAl alot

Comment: @PetSerAI , do you know the meaning of the above `ss32` (sign scale 32 ?) ? It looks to me like a redundant member in the struct.

Comment: `ss32` is include `scale` and `sign` into self as them declared as `union`.

Comment: @PetSerAI , I update the post to offer more details I am stuck at. Please help me clarify with your guidance. I am thankful for your instructions.

Comment: @PetSerAI, Thank you for your help. I still don't understand No1. Actually there is still one more library or class that is not revealed by MS or mono that is used to bridged the gap between `decimal_repr` and Decimal (I think to construct one from another and vice versa). I don't know about it, so I have to do it manually but by this (manual) way, the `ss32` as I asked will not become involved (dummy value will be assigned to it) but `scalesign`'s `sign` and 'scale' will (I do the conversion using these two). That's why I get stuck at the sign clearance.

Comment: In No1, what if I would like to output a Decimal value to a console screen. I will have to compute the above formula then, right ?

Comment: You can get 96-bit integer number `hi:mid:lo` (if you using type that can represent such number, like `BigInterger`, or if you implement long integer arithmetic yourself), get decimal digits of that number and say that `scale` rightmost (less significant) digits is a fractional part and place separator here. But why you need to do this, if you already have `Decimal.ToString` method what can do all this for you and, likely in more efficient way.